# Cross Compiling MATLAB Simulink Model on Windows for Linux target

Tags: matlab, cross-compiling, simulink

I'm trying to use LCC to cross compile a MATLAB Simulink model to a linux binary (host is on windows).

So I started to edit a "Code generation" profile to fit my need. 
I edited the *~/MATLAB\R2011b\rtw\c\ert* profile and tried to add the **-Wf-target=x86/linux** option to the CFLAGS ... but it seems there are also library problems and linking problem ... so I guess this is not the right way to do.

Any of you already done this kind of cross compilation ? What's the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your main constraint is that you don't have MATLAB installed on the target machine, I believe this is the way to go:

Rather than compiling the matlab code, generate C code. This code can then be compiled on any system that you like, without requiring matlab.

This was suggested on <s>[Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/5731)</s>. (Dead link. Copies can be found on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140405072047/http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/5731) and [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/bXvnf-vAs5w/AKgQ42kyW0oJ))

Comment: ok. This worked thanks. I didn't even try to do this because I was thinking that the generated code was using plateform specific code.